# dividing columns in a list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column in a data.frame and have the output of that new column be the division of column 3 by column 2, here is an example:

```
mylist <- list( a=c(0,1,2),b=c(0,2,3),c=c(0,4,5))
```

this returns:

```
$a
[1] 0 1 2

$b
[1] 0 2 3

$c
[1] 0 4 5
```

I would like to return:

```
$a
[1] 0 1 2 2

$b
[1] 0 2 3 1.5

$c
[1] 0 4 5 1.25
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` with `lapply`, divide the 3rd element by the 2nd and concatenate with the original `vector`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) c(x, x[3]/x[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - it works perfectly in the example. However, this doesn't seem to work with the specific data frame that I have - I'm trying to use Bloomberg API to work out, but it seems the data appears in a strange format. i.e. ' data <- bdh(c("MA EQUITY", "FB EQUITY"), c("IS010", "IS033"), start.date=Sys.Date()-365.25*2, options=opt, overrides=ovrd )' has a 'summary' of ''data.frame': 7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date : Date, format: "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31" "2016-06-30" "2016-09-30" ...
 $ IS010: num  2517 2446 2694 2880 2756 ...
 $ IS033: num  1107 1348 1380 1670 1363 ... '

Comment: @lionbow12 The original example you provided is just a list. There are no any data frames. It is probably better if you accept akrun's answer and then post a new question, with proper example reflecting the true structure of your data.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

map(mylist, ~c(., .[3]/.[2]))
$a
[1] 0 1 2 2

$b
[1] 0.0 2.0 3.0 1.5

$c
[1] 0.00 4.00 5.00 1.25
```

Comment: or using the tidyverse: `mylist %>% map(function(x) c(x, x[3]/x[2]))`

Comment: @Jimbou Thanks for your comment. If `map` is the only function needed, there is no need to load `tidyverse`. `purrr` is sufficient.