# Is there an R function to divide a list by a character list

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, numeric, division

I want to divide all the numbers within 5 data frames (each containing 3 columns with 1000 rows), by the corresponding number in 5 character lists (1 element with 1000 rows). So for example:

```
mylist1 <- list(A=c(1,3),B=c(1,1),C=c(0,2))
characterlist1 <- strrep(c("5", "10"), 1 )

(1) mylist1     CharacterList1    Output
     A B C           L      ->    A  B  C 
     1 1 0           5     ->    .2 .2  0
     3 1 2           10     ->   .3 .1 .2

mylist2 <- list(A=c(0,1),B=c(2,2),C=c(1,1))
characterlist2 <- strrep(c("10", "10"), 1 )

(2) mylist2     CharacterList2    Output
     A B C           L      ->    A  B  C 
     0 2 1           10     ->    0 .2 .1
     1 2 1           10     ->   .1 .2 .1
```

For data frames with a single column we can do:

```
(3)  for (j in 1:5) {
   Y=get(paste0("DF",j))
   Z=get(paste0("CharacterList",j))
   Z <- as.numeric(Z)
   Y <- as.vector(Y, mode = "numeric")
   Q <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(Y))
   for (i in 1:length(Y)) {Q[i] <- Z[i]/Y[i]}
```

Is there an easy way to do this with multiple columns as well?

I have gone through [dividing columns in a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712423/dividing-columns-in-a-list-in-r) and converted my data frame into a large list and my current solution is:

```
(4) list2env(lapply(mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "DF"), envir = .GlobalEnv), function(x){
      lapply(x, as.numeric)}
     ), .GlobalEnv)
```

But I receive a "'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" error once I try to enter the result from (4) into (3). Is there something I have missed?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah Got it, thank you for the feedback! I have done my best to edit in a reproducible example

Comment: To start with, why are the divisors *character lists*? You clearly want them to be numeric. So make them numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your *problem description* rather than the (mismatching) code, what you want is the function [`sweep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sweep.html):

```
sweep(df, 1L, numbers, `/`)
```

This divides every column in the input data frame by the vector `numbers`.

It requires

1. Converting each number list to a data.frame (using `as.data.frame`).
2. Converting your character strings to numbers (using `as.numeric`).

If you have multiple data.frames/number vectors, perform the above via `Map`:

```
Map(sweep, df_list, 1L, numbers_list, list(`/`))
```

Note how the sweep function (`/`) has been put into a singleton list here. This prevents `Map` from attempting to treat the function as a list of inputs to iterate over (which would fail). Instead, it now sees a list with a single element, so it recycles its contents. The same happens with the margin argument (`1L`). We could also have put that into a singleton list, but it’s not necessary, since `Map` notices by itself that this isn’t a list input, and needs to be recycled.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Konrad. My apologies that the original post was unclear in certain aspects - I will make sure to do better next time. As for your suggestion, I found it to be the most intuitive solution. I will make use of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, we could loop over the `list` of `data.frame` and divide each of the dataset with the `unlist`ed `list` of vector

```
lapply(lst_df, function(dat) dat/unlist(lst1))
```

Comment: hmm, I receive a "non-numeric argument to binary operator". the lst_df is my regular data frame and lst1 would be my character list?

Answer (score 1):

Get all the 'mylist' and 'characterlist' in a list and use `Map` to perform calculations on them.

```
list1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'mylist\\d+'))
charvec1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'characterlist\\d+'))

result <- Map(function(x, y) do.call(cbind, x)/as.numeric(y),list1,charvec1)

#$mylist1
#       A   B   C
#[1,] 0.2 0.2 0.0
#[2,] 0.3 0.1 0.2

#$mylist2
#       A   B   C
#[1,] 0.0 0.2 0.1
#[2,] 0.1 0.2 0.1
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak! Although I marked Konrad's solution as the correct one, your solution also solved my problem.